# Sql connection timeout for a stored procedure execution from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 1 store procedure to generate some report, its is very complex so it is taking upto 7-8 mins sometimes to generate output.

When i am trying to access from the Webpage ( C# ) i am getting connection time out error.

I have already set remote connection timeout=0 (unlimited) and in connection string also i have tried to supply connection timeout.

I have suppose 6 Lacs around records of bills and i have performing 6 times around sum based on different groups and different dates, so is there any solution to make it faster.

Or any connection timeout workout?

Comment: Will the end-user be interested in seeing 600,000 records at once? What is the point of the report?

Comment: actually user is interested in the total sale of all the products groupwise of the complete month and compare to any other previous month...

Comment: Does the user need to see all the records at once? How about giving a A B C D E F kind of group wise option? Here is what I suggest - ask user what is good for them? possible use cases? I am sure, what is meaningful for users today won't be meaningful after a month. Check with several users to see the purpose/how they will use the report.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with page request timeout. I suppose you start stored procedure execution right on `Page_Load` event and after some time `IIS` close request by timeout.

I'm suggesting to you remove load function from `Page_Load` event and after page loaded send `AJAX` request to server or page to start stored procedure  execution and check execution result from time to time. When result will be ready you can get it by `AJAX` and display to user.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really *connection* timeout that you should be worrying about?

Since you have a long-running command, please ensure that you set CommandTimeout on your SqlCommand to 0.